# Modify a jQuery plugin to use a specific jQuery instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am having a problem with getting the tablesorter jQuery plugin to use the noConflict instance of jQuery which is required because of a mandatory template which loads a different instance of jquery at the very bottom of the page. From what I've read I need to download a local copy of the tablesorter js plugin and modify it so it will use a specific noConflict instance of jQuery. I've tried a few times and can't figure out what modifications to the tablesorter plugin are required to make this work. Any suggestions or documentation on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

**Working Code:**

```
<script src="static/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="static/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#testTable").tablesorter({
        sortInitialOrder: "desc",
    });
}); 
</script>
```

**Non-working Code:**

```
<script src="static/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery_1_12_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="static/jquery.tablesorter.min.modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery_1_12_2(document).ready(function() {      
    jQuery_1_12_2("#testTable").tablesorter({
        sortInitialOrder: "desc",
    });
});
</script>
```

I've tried changing the first and last lines of the tablesorter plugin and a combination of both with no success:

**Tablesorter modifications**

```
(function(jQuery_1_12_2){$.extend({tablesorter:new
...
(jQuery_1_12_2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **order** of the scripts is very important in this case. Don't use the `noConflict()` function until after the plugin has been added to jQuery. Try this:

```
<script src="static/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/jquery.tablesorter.min.modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery_1_12_2 = $.noConflict(true);

jQuery_1_12_2(document).ready(function() {      
    jQuery_1_12_2("#testTable").tablesorter({
        sortInitialOrder: "desc"
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you so much.